# How to export data from mongodb without displaying headers?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to display stored data form the mongodb using the php? But it display's all the header file including data. How to ignore the header information?

It shows like

> { "_id" : ObjectId("550ee694c5c9f2729b066c23"),

I want result as

> 550ee694c5c9f2729b066c23

my php code:

```
$db = new Mongo();
$query = $db->selectDB('test');
$collections = new MongoCollection($query,'demo');
$coursor = $collections->find();
foreach ($coursor as $doc)
{print_r($doc);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the value of the ObjectId() object as a lowercase hexadecimal string using valueOf() method.

```
ObjectId("550ee694c5c9f2729b066c23").valueOf() = 550ee694c5c9f2729b066c23
```

For more details you can check documentation :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/

Answer (score 0):

Actually `{ print_r($doc); }` shows header too. There should be some kind of a **Key** to know which data we need. So we cannot remove them.

```
$db = new Mongo();
$query = $db->selectDB('test');
$collections = new MongoCollection($query,'demo');
$coursor = $collections->find();
foreach ($coursor as $doc)
{
   echo $doc['id'];
}
```

Will give you only `550ee694c5c9f2729b066c23`